# Eclipse C++: How to skip to first breakpoint?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, eclipse-cdt

When I start Eclipse C++ debugger, it starts from the first line side main(), and I have to step line-by-line until the end.  How can I have it skip until the first breakpoint like Visual Studio?  What's the point of having breakpoints if it starts from the beginning like this?

I wish to debug an event-based program, what's the good practice for that?  I want it to start debugging when the event is raised.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are in the C++ perspective, then go to menu `Run` > `Debug Configurations`. Make sure your application is chosen in the left pane, press the Debugger tab, and uncheck `Stop on startup at` checkbox.
[image]